# How to identify air craft based on flight info? Where can I get information about operating carriers and air crafts owned by them?

Tags: plane

I would like to identify air crafts (physically, by serial number, for example).
The main goal is differentiation of air crafts within the same operating carrier (even if their models are same).
Which 3rd-party services can provide that information?

flights, amadeus, flightstats, iata, aviation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is commonly known as the aircraft's `tail` number.

Usually this information is not shared with travelers, however it is sometimes presented in a flightstats tracking response, see 
https://developer.flightstats.com/api-docs/flightstatus/v2/flighttrackresponse